# SQL Query Syntax when adding extra condition check

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that fetches an id and date. I am having some troubles getting the syntax correct:

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $this->table . '` WHERE `id` = ' . $id . ' AND `date` = ' . $date . '');
```

I originally had this without the second check against the date and it worked fine:

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $this->table . '` WHERE `id` = ' . $id . '');
```

but when I add the check for the date things go wrong.

Please help me locate the syntax error. Thank you!

UPDATE:

tried this with no luck still:

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $this->table . '` WHERE `id` = `' . $id. '` AND `date` = `' . $date . '` ');
```

Comment: Because `$date` is a string and need to be quoted.

Comment: You have an extra pair of single quotes at the end of your first example. Put the `)` immediately after `$date`.  `$date);`

Comment: Do you mind adding answer for it @u_mulder. Also Dave I tried your suggestion no luck though :(

Comment: You're using pdo, so you should use parameterized queries. _...and a database design that makes using variables for table names seem like a good idea is usually flawed._

Comment: ok but does anyone mind showing me the correct syntax for what I posted above por favor

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented above, you didn't have quotes around your date. Your syntax would create this SQL:

```
... WHERE `id` = 123 AND `date` = 2018-06-12 -- WRONG
```

But correct syntax is as follows. In other words, a date constant should be delimited by single-quotes.

```
... WHERE `id` = 123 AND `date` = '2018-06-12' -- RIGHT
```

Your second try with back-ticks is also wrong. The back-ticks are for delimited identifiers like column names or table names. This syntax would mean that you're comparing `id` to a column whose name is `123`, and I assume you don't have such a column. Same for the back-ticks around the date—it's interpreted as a column named `2018-06-12` which is unlikely. MySQL does not treat back-ticks the same as single-quotes.

```
... WHERE `id` = `123` AND `date` = `2018-06-12` -- WRONG
```

However, there's a much easier solution. You won't have to worry about quotes if you use query parameters:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE `id` = ? AND `date` = ?";
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$id, $date]);
```

You're already using `prepare()`, so you should use it to its best advantage and use query parameters (the `?` placeholders) instead of interpolating variables into your SQL query string.

You don't need quotes around strings or dates when you use parameters. In fact, you must NOT use quotes to delimit the `?` parameter placeholders.

Notice I also show the PHP syntax for putting a variable directly into a string without breaking the string and using `.` for concatenation. You can do this if your PHP string is delimited with double-quotes. Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing for details.

Comment: thanks very much for the thorough explanation! works great